# Unordered_map with vector usage

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<unsigned int, vector<unsigned int> > duplicates;
```

Anad I would like to insert:

```
duplicates.insert(make_pair(1, 2));
duplicates.insert(make_pair(1, 5));
duplicates.insert(make_pair(1, 6));
```

into the vector because they share the same key. I use a for loop for inserting pairs. How can I initialise the vector if no items share the same key and it is the first time that I find that key without searching the whole unordered_map?

I do not want to first use find (to get the vector if exist) and then insert. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but perhaps you might find use in something like [`unordered_multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/)?

> Unordered multimaps are associative containers that store elements formed by the combination of a key value and a mapped value, much like `unordered_map` containers, but **allowing different elements to have equivalent keys**.

Comment: Hm. Yes this sound as a solution. Can you give an example on how can I iterate over the multiple results of a key? And if its ok to use std::tr1::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int > duplicates; as I will not need the vector anymore?

Comment: `std::tr1::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, unsigned int > duplicates;` should work. Take a look at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/) for an example of iterating through all values with the same key.

Comment: @salamis Sure, glad I could help. Mark the answer if it has solved your problem.